# Why does badge notification not show in the taskbar for single window packaged winforms app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, uwp

I have made a winforms app and changed the target framework to net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0. This gives me access to Windows.UI.Notifications. I use this to make a badge notification with the following C# code:

```
var xmlText = "<badge value="alert"/>";
var xmlDoc = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlText);
var badgeNotification = new Windows.UI.Notifications.BadgeNotification(xmlDoc);

var bu = Windows.UI.Notifications.BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication();

bu.Update(badgeNotification);
```

This correctly shows a badge in the start menu when the packaged app is run, but not in the task bar, on my Windows 10 computer. When a second window is opened in the app, the badge shows up in the task bar, but when the second window is closed again, the badge disappears. Is this intended behavior? If so, how can I show a badge in the task bar for a packaged winforms app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem to have disabled this behavior for Win32 using MSIX, but the issue is still open:

"For Win32 apps using MSIX, we disabled the UWP badges from appearing on taskbar, since Win32 apps can use ITaskbarList to create custom taskbar "badges"."

https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1919

So it seems to be the intended behaviour, but failing silently gives me more like a bug vibe. I pulled some hair thinking it was something wrong with my own code.

I am not aware of any other workaround in MAUI so I also opened an issue on the MAUI project:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13994